# Выдает ошибку sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Сделал программу которая работает с базой данных, использую sqlite3.

Упаковываю эту программу в экзешник, при запуске напрямую через этот экзешник все корректно работает, но мне понадобилось запускать мою программу не напрямую а через сторонний файл, в данном случае через json файл.

Через этот файл я получаю нужную мне информацию, запускаю программу способом: правой кнопкой на json файл -> открыть с помощью -> указываю свою программу. Для этого в программе я использую такой код:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    with sqlite3.connect("./data_bases/data.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()

        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            file = sys.argv[1]
            print(sys.argv)
            with open(f"{file}", "r") as out_file:
                data = json.load(out_file)
                app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
                otherWindow_3(data)
                sys.exit(app.exec())
        else:
            katalog()
```

Ну и при попытке открыть через этот json файл, выдает ошибку:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Пробовал менять путь к базе данных, писал полный путь, не помогло. Пробовал саму базу данных перенести в другую папку, думал что нет доступа к папке где находится база, не помогло.

Comment: Кстати если вы ожидаете что этот `with sqlite3.connect` закроет базу данных, то вынужден вас огорчить - так вы уходите просто в транзакцию. нужно использовать `closing` из `contextlib`

Comment: Понял, спасибо за совет!

Comment: Вы сделайте `print(os.getcwd())` и увидите какая рабочая директория устанавливается для каждого вызова. В общем то вам нужно делать путь к базе от самого скрипта (правда тут и при полном пути должно работать, так что не знаю)

Comment: Сделал код для записи os.getcwd(), при запуске скрипта рабочая директория записывается  в выбранный текстовый файл, при запуске экзешника как всегда все работает, а при запуске через файл, опять падает эта ошибка, но рабочая директория не записывается в файл, хотя скрипт должен это сделать в первую очередь, более того, я закомментировал часть кода где менеджер контекста производит конект с БД и перевел прогу в экзешник, по идее он должен записать директорию и закнчить работу, когда просто экзешник запускаю так и работает, а когда пытаюсь открыть через файл все равно кидает ту же ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По пробуйте задать полный путь к файлу в формате который я укажу:

```
with sqlite3.connect("C:\\users\\user\\data_bases\\data.db") as db:
```

Только укажите свой полный путь

Comment: Так и сделал, не помогло. Как обычно если сам экзешник запускать, то все работает, а если через другой файл, то выдает ошибку. Пробовал перенести БД в другую папку и соответственно поменять к ней путь, не помогло, тоже самое с самой с прогой делал, не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема решилась. Изначально проблема действительно была в неправильном указании пути к БД, но потом я исправил эту ошибку, записал полный путь. Но ошибка не пропадала. Ошибка была в том, что я создал экзешник с таким же именем, но пути у них были разные и когда я пытался открыть файл методом: правой кнопкой на json файл -> открыть с помощью -> указываю свою новую упакованную в exe программу, то этот файл открывался не через мою новую программу, а через старую с тем же именем, хотя путь у нее другой. Не знаю с чем это связано, но так видимо работает Windows.